# Synchronized across instances of object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I have an object Rotor which has a goalSpeed and a currentSpeed. Each one tries to change its currentSpeed to match the goalSpeed set. I have 4 of these rotors running ing 4 separate threads. Each one gets assigned a new goalSpeed periodically by a controller.

When I attempt in each Rotor to change its currentSpeed, I cannot ever exceed the sum of all rotor's currentSpeed to exceed X value. sum(currentSpeed(Rotor1) + ... + currentSpeed(Rotor2)) !> X.

Here is my issue: when I check wether I can increase the current speed of a Rotor, I make an if statement on the sum of speeds condition. However, it is possible that right after this check, since each rotor is a separate thread that another one changes its value. Therefore my check in the other thread is not valid anymore. How can I make sure that while I'm in the setNewSpeed() method of one rotor, no other rotor will change its current speed?

```
class Rotor implements Runnable {
    private int id;
    private int goalSpeed;
    private int currentSpeed;
    private Controller controller;
    private int Y;
    private int failedAttempts;
    private int successAttempts;
    private int maxSpeed;

    public int getSuccessAttempts() {
        return successAttempts;
    }

    public void setSuccessAttempts(int successAttempts) {
        this.successAttempts = successAttempts;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    public int getFailedAttempts() {
        return failedAttempts;
    }

    public Rotor(Controller c, int Y, int id){
        this.controller = c;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.id = id;
        this.currentSpeed = 0;
        this.failedAttempts = 0;
        this.goalSpeed = 0;
        this.maxSpeed = 0;
        this.successAttempts = 0;
    }

    synchronized public void setGoalSpeed(int s){
        this.goalSpeed = s;
    }

    public int getCurrentSpeed(){
        return currentSpeed;
    }

    synchronized private void setNewSpeed(){
        int currentDrain = 0;
        for(Rotor r : controller.getRotors()){
            currentDrain = currentDrain + r.getCurrentSpeed();
        }
        if((currentDrain + (goalSpeed - currentSpeed)) > 20){
            //we cannot increase by total amount because drain too high
            System.out.println("failed");
            this.failedAttempts++;
            currentSpeed = currentSpeed + (20 - currentDrain);
            System.out.println("currentSpeed:" + currentSpeed);
        } else {
            System.out.println("success");
            successAttempts++;
            currentSpeed = goalSpeed;
        }
//      System.out.println("goalSpeed:" + goalSpeed);
//      System.out.println("currentDrain:" + currentDrain);

}

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true){
                setNewSpeed();
                if(currentSpeed > maxSpeed){
                    maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
                }

                Thread.sleep(Y);
            }   
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Rotor " + id + ": checks=" + (int)(successAttempts + failedAttempts) + ", success rate=" + successAttempts + ", failedAttempts=" + failedAttempts + ", max=" + maxSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize on a lock that's shared between all the rotors. Now each of them is synchronizing on their own lock (i.e. `this`), so even though the method is synchronized, it can be called on different objects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to synchronize them all is to use a `static synchronized` method.

That said, using an explicit lock object shared among the instances is probably a better approach.

Comment: He can't access the instance properties from a static method.

Comment: @Kayaman However he can pass the instance in a parameter, and then access private methods or even private members of the passed instance.

Comment: Sure, if he switches the design around.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should not write

`synchronized private void setNewSpeed()` and `synchronized public void setGoalSpeed(int s)`

but     `private synchronized void setNewSpeed()` and `public synchronized void setGoalSpeed(int s)` if you want to respect conventions and standard.

2) You declare two synchronized methods in your `Rotor Runnable` class but it makes no sense because in the synchronized methods you don't manipulate data shared between the threads.

3) You have multiple ways to address your problem.
A flexible solution consists of using a artificial object shared between the threads and performing the lock on this object when you call the `setNewSpeed()` method.
 It allows each tread to wait for the lock to be removed before entering in `setNewSpeed()`.

Here is the idea to implement the solution :

- Before instantiating the `Rotor`, create the shared object in this way :

  `Object lockObject = new Object();`
- change `public Rotor(Controller c, int Y, int id)` to  `public Rotor(Controller c, int Y, int id, Object lockObject)`
- invoke the constructor of `Rotor` by adding the same `lockObject` instance for all `Rotors` which you want synchronize between them the speed change.
- Store the `lockObject` as an instance field of the Rotor in the constructor body.
- In `Rotor` use the `lockObject` to make the synchronization in this way :

sample code :

```
 private void setNewSpeed(){
     synchronized(lockObject){
         ... your actual processing
      }
 }
```